# discord.py: name the channel from where the command was executed

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to create a principled bot on moderation and I am unable to put the channel name in the moderation logs. I have already tried with ctx.channel but as I had already guessed it is useless.
Do you know how to do it? I am recently learning discord.py

Code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def slowmode(ctx, seconds: int, ):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0xa61022
    )
    embed.set_author(
        name=f'La modalità lenta durerà {seconds} secondi',
        icon_url=f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}'
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
    await ctx.channel.edit(slowmode_delay=seconds)
    channel_ability = ctx.channel
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0xFFD000
    )
    embed.set_author(
        name=f'{ctx.author._user} ha settato ad {seconds} secondi la modalità lenta su {channel_ability}',
        icon_url=f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}'
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Secondi modalità lenta: {seconds}')
    embed.add_field(
        name='Settata da:',
        value=f'{ctx.author._user}',
        inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Canale dove è stata settata la slowmode:',
        value=f'{channel_ability}',
        inline=True
    )
    channel = client.get_channel(729553772547932190)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right when you tried `ctx.channel` except that `ctx.channel` is a [`TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel) object, not a string. To access the channel name, you just have to write `ctx.channel.name`.

Documentation for the `ctx` argument [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context).

Comment: in the end I managed to use `ctx.channel.mention` which mentions the channel.
Thanks for the help `ctx.channel.name` also works